# Proper way of storing data in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

What would be the best way to store data? Like if my project has `company` and `brand` collection and Schema is like

### In `company` collection

```
{
company_name : X,
brand_id : [1,2] // here I store the id's of brands that has same company 
}
```

### In `brand` collection

```
{
brand_name : y,
price : 10;
}
```

So for saving data of same company,i use step as-

1 - insert `brand_name` and `price` in `brand` collection.

2 - insert company_name in company collection and update brand_id from id  obtained result from brand_collection.

EX-

```
         brand.insert({brand_name : y,price : 10},function(err,brand_result){

                 company.insert({company_name : X},function(error,company_result){
                          company.update({company_name : X},{
                               $push : {
                                 brand_id : brand_result.id
                                 }
                          },function(errs,result){
                              res.send({message : 'Data save'});
                           });  
                       });
                  });
```

I don't know how but according to me it is not a good method because
First of all this this takes so much time in inserting data

and second When I insert data from **CSV file** then i am not able to update `brand_id` in `company collection` for different brand of same company.

So please give me some suggestion and suggest some better method.

Comment: In your situation would it be a reverse document mapping. Such that the "company" has many "brands"? If that is the case, then you may want to look into storing the reference to the company in the brand instead.

Comment: Does the CSV file have both company and brand information?

Comment: @RickyM reverse document mapping can not possible because if i anyone enter data like a single company and brand ..and after sometimes someone enter data with same company and different brand then  there will exist a problem.

Comment: And CSV file has single information like a file of full company information and other with full brand information.

Comment: The way you are explaining it makes me think that you are going to read in CSV files and immediately insert them into the database. One issue is that you are probably not checking to see if the data will produce duplicates. I would always check to see if something exists first then update if it does to prevent anyone else from entering the same information.